# Grunt spawned process not capturing output

Tags: node.js, process, gruntjs, spawn

I have spawned a process using Grunt, but nothing that is written to the output stream (such as `console.log`) is being displayed in the console.

I would like Grunt to display any output from the process.

```
grunt.util.spawn(
  { cmd: 'node'
  , args: ['app.js']
  , opts:
      { stdio:
          [ process.stdin
          , process.stout
          , process.stderr
          ]
      }
  })
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try setting it to `opts: {stdio: 'inherit'}`. Otherwise you can pipe the output:

```
var child = grunt.util.spawn({
  cmd: process.argv[0], // <- A better way to find the node binary
  args: ['app.js']
});
child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
```

Or if you want to modify the output:

```
child.stdout.on('data', function(buf) {
    console.log(String(buf));
});
```

Comment: `stdio: 'inherit'` does the trick, and thanks for the tip of finding the Node binary!