# execute a node command from a grunt task

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have a grunt task from which I would like to run a node command. The command is not giving any error when I run it, but I was expecting some console output from the task, which I don't seem to be getting at all.

What am I missing in order to run this node task?

```
grunt.registerTask('asyncfoo', 'My "asyncfoo" task.', function() {
    // Force task into async mode and grab a handle to the "done" function.
    var done = this.async();
    // Run some sync stuff.
    grunt.log.writeln('Processing task...');


    grunt.util.spawn({ cmd: 'node', args: ['S3ListBuckets.js']});

    // And some async stuff.
    setTimeout(function() {
        grunt.log.writeln('All done!');
        done();
    }, 1000);
});
```

!-- if someone else is wanting to do something similar here is the code

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('asyncfoo', 'My "asyncfoo" task.', function() {
    // Force task into async mode and grab a handle to the "done" function.
    var done = this.async();
    // Run some sync stuff.
    grunt.log.writeln('Processing task...');

    grunt.util.spawn({ cmd: 'node', args: ['S3ListBuckets.js'], opts: {stdio: 'inherit'}});

});

};
```

!-- list buckets

```
var fs = require('fs');

var aws = require('aws-sdk');

aws.config.loadFromPath('./grunt-aws.json');

var s3 = new aws.S3();

s3.listBuckets(function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
    console.log("Error:", err);
   }
else {
    for (var index in data.Buckets) {
        var bucket = data.Buckets[index];
        console.log("Bucket: ", bucket.Name, ' : ', bucket.CreationDate);
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15045126/519995  suggests using the parameter `opts: {stdio: 'inherit'}` to have the spawned output streamed into the parent output stream.

That same answer also lists other alternatives: listening to data event, or piping the streams as you wish.

Also, using timeouts to wait for async tasks is NOT a good idea. If all you are waiting for is the spawned process you can use a callback to know when its done. If you have more complex sync I suggest starting a new StackOverflow question.

Comment: Hi @Iftah, thanks for the answer. That did the trick. In terms of the timeout, I was lifted straight from the grunt api. I have not intention of using it.