# Show output in Grunt as command runs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, gruntjs, spawn

Here I get no output and the command runs forever:

```
grunt.registerTask('serve', function () {
    var done = this.async();

    grunt.util.spawn({
        cmd: 'jekyll',
        args: ['serve'],
        stdio: 'inherit'
    }, function (err, res, exit_code) {
        res.stdout && console.info(res.stdout);
        exit_code && console.error(res.stderr);
        done(err);
    });
});
```

I want output (and the command to run until error or interrupt).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answers, @Lihau-Tan was close to the right one.

Combining that answer with my attempt and I came up with this solution:

```
grunt.registerTask('serve', function () {
    var child = grunt.util.spawn({
        cmd: 'jekyll',
        args: ['serve', '-P', process.env.PORT || 4001],
        stdio: 'inherit'
    }, this.async());

    child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
    child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
grunt.registerTask('serve', function(){
    var done = this.async();

    var child = grunt.util.spawn({
       cmd: 'jekyll',
       args: ['serve']
    }, function(){
       ...
    });

    child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
    child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
});
```

See: [Grunt spawned process not capturing output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044307/grunt-spawned-process-not-capturing-output)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [grunt log](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.log)

Following functions available

```
grunt.log.write(msg)
grunt.log.writeln([msg])
grunt.log.error([msg])
grunt.log.errorlns(msg)
grunt.log.ok([msg])
grunt.log.oklns(msg)
grunt.log.subhead(msg)
grunt.log.writeflags(obj, prefix)
grunt.log.debug(msg)
```